# modelling of an equation

Tags: derivatives

A scientist is studying a population of mice on an island.
The number of mice, N, in the population after t, months of the study of the modelled is $$N=\frac{900}{3+7e^{-0.25t}}$$

They said show that $$\frac{dN}{dt}=\frac{N(300-N)}{1200}$$

I did it.

The next question I am not getting is:

The rate of growth is a maximum after T months.

Find according to the model, the value of T.

---

I got no idea, the only i could think is

$\frac{dN}{dt}=0$, so $N=300$ and if I sub this into

$N=\frac{900}{3+7e^{-0.25t}}$

$300=\frac{900}{3+7e^{-0.25t}}$

$e^{-0.25t}=0$ so it makes no sense.

Any help please

Comment: You have identified when the rate of growth is 0.

Comment: so what is the value of T

Comment: That would be telling! You maximize N by putting $\frac{dN}{dt} = 0$. You want to maximize $\frac{dN}{dt}$ so....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The growth is $\frac{dN}{dt}$ and the rate of growth is :

$$\frac{d^2N}{dt}=-2N+300$$

$$\frac{d^2N}{dt}=-2N+300=0$$

$$N=150$$

Plugging this in equation you get $T≈3.338$